# Display multiband raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, multi-band

I have a multiband raster (3 bands) that I want to display in QGIS.  I can display each band as a singleband without trouble, but if I try display from multi-band (properties in style) I get very little of the image.  Tips for what I am doing wrong?  I am using the option to load the max/min values from extent.  See screen shot of the properties selected below, as well as a screen shot of just the blue band

[image: Screen shot of options for multiband in Properties]

[image: Screen shot of just the Blue band]

ETA: Checking that this really is multi-band and not single band.  I have copied the properties using the check that @ahmadhanb has shown in their response.  3 bands are mentioned.

```
Driver
GDAL provider
GTiff
GeoTIFF
Dataset Description
filepath/SRTM_W84.tif
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Band 1
RepresentationType=ATHEMATIC
STATISTICS_COVARIANCES=11535.08822294172,8768.945936995617,6876.945116165363
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
STATISTICS_MEAN=195.17337427807
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORX=1
STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORY=1
STATISTICS_STDDEV=107.40152787237
Band 2
RepresentationType=ATHEMATIC
STATISTICS_COVARIANCES=8768.945936995617,8122.704384270356,6278.396582608941
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
STATISTICS_MEAN=209.64313615503
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORX=1
STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORY=1
STATISTICS_STDDEV
0 
Data Type
Byte - Eight bit unsigned integer
Pyramid overviews
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
Layer Extent (layer original source projection)
115.0000000000000000,4.9990704361995046 : 130.0001196658648723,20.0000000000000000
Band
Band 1
Band No
1
No Stats
No stats collected yet
Band
Band 2
Band No
2
No Stats
No stats collected yet
Band
Band 3
Band No
3
No Stats
No stats collected yet =90.126047202073
Band 3
RepresentationType=ATHEMATIC
STATISTICS_COVARIANCES=6876.945116165363,6278.396582608941,5652.621835039329
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
STATISTICS_MEAN=169.71246008137
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORX=1
STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORY=1
STATISTICS_STDDEV=75.183920056348
Dimensions
X: 18521 Y: 18522 Bands: 3
X : 9261,Y 9261
X : 4631,Y 4631
X : 2316,Y 2316
X : 1158,Y 1158
X : 579,Y 579
X : 290,Y 290
X : 145,Y 145
Origin
115,20
Pixel Size
0.000809898,-0.000809898
No Data Value 0 Data Type Byte - Eight bit unsigned integer 
Pyramid  overviews Layer Spatial Reference System 
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
Layer Extent (layer original source projection)
15.0000000000000000,4.9990704361995046 : 
0.0001196658648723,20.0000000000000000 
Band Band 1 Band No 1 No Stats No stats collected yet 
Band Band 2 Band No 2 No Stats No stats collected yet 
Band Band 3 Band No 3 No Stats No stats collected yet
```

Comment: This means it is not raw elevation data, which means it does contain elevation information. It is just a picture (RGB picture). If you want to show real elevation data, this data is useless. You need to download real SRTM data if you want to see the elevation.

Comment: Thanks @ahmadhanb -  looks like I've been sent the wrong file.  I'll follow up.  Appreciate your help sorting this out.

Comment: By looking at the statistics the deviation looks rather scewed. For example band 3 has mean=169 and max =255. I would have a try with a) in Load min/max values use Mean +/- standard deviation x 1.0. Remember to press Load and b) when you have the new min/max values select from the Contrast enhancement menu "Stretch to MinMax." Now you have there "No enhancement" so you have not changed the default rendering at all yet.

Answer (score 1):

In your first image with the multiband raster you did not select any select any option from Load min/max values. You need to select one of them and click load as you can see below:

[image]

Then the statistics of the raster will be calculated based on the zoom view. If you want to view your image based on the full min.max statistics of your image, use `Full` option not `Current` and click on `Load`.

**Updata**

I think you are working with single band raster not multiband raster. SRTM data is always single band image. To confirm of whether you are using single band or multiband, go to `Layer properties -> Metadata ->` Scroll to the bottom of the data until you see title `Band` as you can see below

[image]

Under the Band No. it shows the number of bands. If it is only `1`, it means you are dealing with only one band. If it is `3` this means you are dealing with three bands and so on.

Comment: I've tried both cumulative and min/max with the load - and it doesn't really display anything.  In the image above Cumulative, Current and Estimate have been selected.

Comment: Try to change the `Contrast enhancement` from `No enhancement` to `Stretch to MinMax` for example, and see if any changes happened.

Comment: Nothing displays if I choose that option.  Thanks for your suggestions to try sort this out @ahmadhanb

Comment: I noticed that you are using SRTM_WGS84. Are you sure that it is multiband raster. SRTM is always single band. If you want to give a color to your SRTM, you should use `Singleband pseudocolor` from `Render Type` not `Multiband Color`

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure - first time I've dealt with a raster of this sort.  I just know there are 3 bands, and that if you use singleband you can choose 1 of the bands at a time and display different things.  I assumed therefore that it was multiband.

Comment: @Esme_ I updated my answer to guide you how to check if you have single band or multibands.